# HighCharts - Enable the markers for the series which has only single data point?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

How do I  to enable the markers only for those series which has only a single data point.
Here I have disabled it for the whole chart. So then the 3rd series doesn't shows up until mouse over.

```
     plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mithun146/ef6dtjon/2/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable the marker for that specific series, like this:

```
series: [
  ...,
  {
    marker: {
      enabled: true
    },
    data: [10]
  }
]
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/ak0m8r75/